# How to track record's field value updates in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service, ui-record-api

I have a component which I'd like to present the real-time value of my record's fields. Considering simplified [getFieldValue(record, field) Docs Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value):

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card
        title="WireGetFieldValue"
        icon-name="standard:account">
        <template if:true={account.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <p><lightning-formatted-number 
                    format-style="currency"
                    value={revenue}
                    currency-code="USD">
                    </lightning-formatted-number>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <lightning-formatted-date-time
                    weekday="long"
                    month="short"
                    year="numeric"
                    day="2-digit"
                    hour="2-digit"
                    minute="2-digit"
                    value={created}>
                    </lightning-formatted-date-time>
                </p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import REVENUE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue';
import CREATED_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.CreatedDate';

const fields = [REVENUE_FIELD, CREATED_FIELD];

export default class WireGetValue extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    account;

    get revenue() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, REVENUE_FIELD);
    }

    get created() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, CREATED_FIELD);
    }
}
```

JS-Meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Wire Get Value</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Account</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I thought that the `@wire` decorator would serve that purpose, but it works only for Edit / Inline Edit actions. After updating the value from another place (Apex Anonymous window, another web browser's tab etc.), it doesn't change to the new one.

Is there a way to make it work for every type of record update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more general approach you need to use `Change Data Capture`. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm (in short Platform Events)

You need add `Account` to `Change Data Capture` in setup and then subscribe to  `/data/AccountChangeEvent` event with `lightning/empApi` component https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

**UPDATE**:
without losing context

```
export default class Component extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (response) => {
       //handle response.data.payload
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Successfully subscribed");
    });
  }
}
```

with losing context

```
export default class Component extends LightningElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, function(response) {
       //handle response.data.payload
    }.bind(this))
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Successfully subscribed");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I try to register to the ``channelName = '/data/AccountChange'``, but then I receive the following error in the console: ``Received error from server:  {"clientId":"199fmh3kfzq4vtc1l72gb5w6h7xq","channel":"/meta/subscribe","id":"32","subscription":"/data/AccountChange","error":"400::The channel specified is not valid {/data/AccountChange}","successful":false}``

Do you know what might be a reson for that? I have added ``Account (Account)`` to the selected entities in ``Change Data Capture`` Setup.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrectly it should be `ChangeEvent` suffix) `/data/AccountChangeEvent` together

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Event was captured but I couldn't update fields on the component. It turned out that in the callback method the context of LWC is lost and ``this`` didn't work properly. I modified my code respectively to sfdcfox' advice in the [showToast from messageCallback function of empApi](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297863/showtoast-from-messagecallback-function-of-empapi) question and now it works fine. Could you please add this information to your answer? I'll accept it then.

Comment: to be honest don't know why you were losing context because if you use arrow functions (`=>`) in callback it should work. I'll add 2 examples in the answer

Comment: @PrzemysławTamoń added 2 examples to the code to handle both options